# ThreadLocal set/remove using AOP inside Completable.supplyAsync() block

Tags: java, aop, completable-future, thread-local

I am workin on a multi-tenant REST API project using Spring Boot 3. Our Repository layer is non-reactive (a design decision that i cannot change), while using WebFlux on Controller layer. Current solution to pick correct datasource is using Spring's AbstractRoutingDatasource.

We are setting/removing ThreadLocal tenant-id on Service layer by extracting tenant-id from method parameter inside CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() block.

For every Service layer method that needs to invoke database have to set/remove tenant-id manually, which I don't like.

I am looking for a more neat solution (maybe using AOP/ or other approach) to set/remove tenant-id on each Service layer method (**inside CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() block**) without writing repeated code manually.

Thank you!

**Service Layer Method**

```
public Mono findMyData(MyRequest req) {

    return Mono.fromFuture(() -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        // Setting Tenant Id on ThreadLocal object
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(req.getTenantId());
        
        repository.findAll();

        // Removing Tenant Id from ThreadLocal object
        TenantContext.remove();

    }));
}
```

**TenantContext class that holds ThreadLocal**

```
public class TenantContext {
private static final ThreadLocal<String> CURRENT_TENANT = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static String getCurrentTenant() {
    return CURRENT_TENANT.get();
}

public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {
    CURRENT_TENANT.set(tenant);
}

public static void remove() {
    CURRENT_TENANT.remove();
}
```

}

**My Implementation of AbstractRoutingDataSource**

```
public class MultiTenantDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
@Override
protected String determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
}
```

}

Relatively new to AOP and not sure if I can access to method parameter object and inject statements  inside method.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not an active Spring user and not experienced in reactive programming. I can certainly help you with the AOP solution, but I would like to have a complete, minimal example (incl. dummy database, H2 or so), ideally as a Maven project on GitHub. If you can provide one, I shall take a look.